3Dx SectionService Runtime-Error '430' when set the service object
This question is regarding 3D Experience automation via VBA. I tried the Macro example shipped with 3Dx to create a section, it returns the error '430' Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface 3Dx. If I create the section manually via 3Dx GUI tool there is no issue. I already manually added a Markup to the product but I still get the same error. I also tried to get some other services like MeasurementService without any issues.
Dim oSectionService as SectionService
Set oSectionService = CATIA.ActiveEditor.GetService("SectionService") '~~~ Error 

